# MongoDB suddenly stopped working (MongoServerSelectionError:m ReplicaSetNoPrimary

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

For some reason, I'm receiving this error when connecting to my MongoDB in replit. It was all working fine like 4 hours ago, and been connecting with it for 2 weeks now.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ac-8q8dm3y-shard-00-00.5ldtt3z.mongodb.net
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/Bojji/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:292:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'primary' => [ServerDescription],
      'secondary' => [ServerDescription],
      'secondary' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-q5c7wq-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Here's my connection string

```
mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0.5ldtt3z.mongodb.net/bot?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Here's my js code to connect

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const mySecret = process.env['dbToken'];

let dbConnection;

module.exports = {
  connectToDb: (cb) => {
    MongoClient.connect(mySecret)
    .then((client) => {
      dbConnection = client.db();
      return cb();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return cb(err);
    })
  },
  getDb: () => dbConnection
}
```

Here are the things I tried but to no avail:

- Used Google DNS.
- Added my IP in whitelist including 0.0.0.0/0
- Disabled Windows Defender
- Updated my Mongo User password.
- Restarted my router.
- Allow outbound port 27015-27017 in firewall

Here are other information:

- Mongodb Cluster version: 5.0.14
- Mongodb Cluster Tier: M0 Sandbox (General)
- Mongodb type: Replica Set - 3 nodes
- Mongodb Package version: 4.13.0
- Windows OS: Windows 11

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ? I've the same issue that started some days ago. In the middle of a script: The first request passes correctly, but then, some minutes after, I receive this error.
This script was running fine for months.

Comment: There's no fix. It's a problem on the IDE, in my case, replit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll continue to dig my issue then. It's super weird as we didn't change anything.

Comment: @Gp2mv3 if that is replit too, they said they're working on it already, or at least gathering information about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround available within replit. I hosted my app elsewhere for now.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest solution: Just try**

```
telnet cluster0-shard-00-00.XXXX.mongodb.net 27017
```

Telnet to primary and all secondary clusters. It will create quick connection and MongoDb Cluster should connect properly.

If telnet throws error then try to check with whitelisting IP in cluster or restart computer.